# Getting symbol names from a Mac app's call stack

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging, symbolicate

I have a stack trace from my Mac App Store app, that I'd like to read to help diagnose a problem the user is experiencing. I have the dSYM file and original archived build, but I do not have a full crash report. All I would like to know is the name of the methods in the stack trace (you can see two of them for **MyAppName**, below). I have not been able to get `lldb` or `atos` to give me this information. This is what the stack trace looks like:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92fdd25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff918dbe75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92ebb4f5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 245
3   MyAppName                           0x0000000108e91c6b MyAppName + 126059
4   MyAppName                           0x0000000108e7556f MyAppName + 9583
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d883099 -[NSToolbarButton sendAction:to:] + 75
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8830e8 -[NSToolbarButton sendAction] + 65
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d436f0c -[NSToolbarItemViewer mouseDown:] + 4897
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d352a58 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 11296
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d2f15d4 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2021
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d1419f9 -[NSApplication run] + 646
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d12c783 NSApplicationMain + 940
12  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff87df35fd start + 1
13  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

To get a symbol (say, for level 3 above), what command can I use? When I was calling `lldb`, it wasn't even clear if I should be using the hex address or the offset, if that's what the 126059 is on level 3.

**Update**

According to the [`atos` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/atos.1.html), it looks like I should invoke it like so:

```
xcrun atos -arch x86_64 -o MyAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppName -l <LOADED ADDRESS> 0x0000000108e91c6b
```

What would I use as the loaded address, though? All I have is what I pasted above. Whether I use `0x0000000000000001`, `0x00007fff87df35fd`, or leave out `-l` entirely, I get `0x0000000108e91c6b` (the address I specified) printed back to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

In most tools that dump stack traces (particularly CrashReporter) there's a section at the bottom of the report with all the images currently loaded in the program, their UUID's and their load addresses.  You should always make sure to get that info along with the stack trace since that's what tells you the load address of the binary, and also will ensure that you have the right version of the debug information, since you can match the UUID against the UUID in the dSYM or binary.

You might be able to use the "Symbol Name + offset" part of the trace to figure out the load address, however.  Generally, this last column is the offset of the address in the backtrace from the closest unstripped symbol in that binary.  So you just find the address of that symbol in your stored binary, add the offset to that address, and subtract that from the address listed in the third column above.  In lldb, you can find the address of a symbol using:

```
(lldb) image lookup -n <SymbolName>
```

That calculation will give you the "slide" of the binary from its default load address.  Then run lldb on your binary and do:

```
(lldb) image load -f MyAppName -s <Calculated Slide>
```

Now you can look up the addresses from MyAppName in the stack trace using:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va <ADDRESS>
```

However, main executables are usually totally stripped - since they generally don't provide symbols for use by any other component of the system, so there aren't any symbols left.  In that case, I would guess MyAppName in the listing above is just the __TEXT.__text section of the binary, though I'm not 100% sure about that.  Anyway if that is right, you can find the default load address of that section by loading the binary in lldb and doing:

```
(lldb) image dump sections MyAppName
```

Then do the same calculation listed above.